# Talend Bigdata & Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, talend, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to write data from Talend to Hortonworks sandbox Hadoop setup.

While excuting the talend job to send the data, it generates the following exception and warning in console. However, Talend job creates the file on Hortonworks environment but not able to write data there.

[image]

> [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3740 [statistics] connected
>   [WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable Exception in component tHDFSOutput_1
>   java.io.IOException: DataStreamer Exception:      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:697)
>   Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1611)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1362)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:589)
>   [WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - DataStreamer Exception
>   java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1611)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1362)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:589)
>   [statistics] disconnected [ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient -
>   Failed to close inode 17106 java.io.IOException: DataStreamer
>   Exception:    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:697)
>   Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1611)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1409)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1362)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:589)
>   Job test ended at 16:50 18/03/2017. [exit code=1]

Comment: `Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException`. Any chance that the NameNode is not accessible the way you are trying?

Comment: I am able to create the file by using the same NameNode which is accessible. The only problem I am facing to write/stream data through that NameNode. Please suggest how to get rid of this problem.